# Huge 2d map world game?

Tags: java, c++, performance, 2d-games

I've been thinking about a game idea and I was thinking of some technical stuff and came up with that the map would need to be 360,000x360,000 pixels in size which generated randomly.

360,000 * 360,000 == 129,600,000,000 pixels in total.
assume that I only using a 16-color palette, so each pixel can specify its color using only four bits.
129,600,000,000 pixels * 4 bits per pixel == 518,400,000,000 bits.Divide by 8 bits per byte gives us 64,800,000,000 bytes. Divide by 1024 bytes per kilobyte, and then by 1024 kilobytes per megabyte, and you get approximately 61,798 megabytes. Let's round that off and call it an even 60 gigabytes.

so I divide the map world into small pieces "tiles".
When I tilesize it into 360x360, I can represent my game world with ((360,000 / 360) * (360,000 / 360)) = (10^6) million tiles. The only data I need per tile is the id number of the tile. so the data stored in the ram memory of the machine is array of 360*360 which size is 360*360*4=518,400 bit which is 64,800 byte which is 63.28 kilobyte which is 0.061 megabyte

It's okay but I think I still have the problem.
the displayed tile of the map world will be 360*360 pixel, as the player can move the mouse to [right, left, down, up], when the player move the mouse e.g. up so I have to delete the last row of the tile displayed and display as a first row the last row of the above tile of the current. it also be more complex if the current tile displayed is combination of four tiles but it's not issue it's need only coding skills.
but the issue is I have to memories all tiles into machine ram so I go to the first point again the memory space.

how I can build a map of 360,000x360,000 pixels and be able to handle it

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: So you are here just to share with us your idea I suppose?

Comment: so, yeah, what's your question already ?

Comment: how I can build a map of 360,000x360,000 pixels and be able to handle it

Comment: You'll need to procedurally generate these tiles. If you need to store pixel for pixel data then, *at the absolute least*, use an encoding like PNG to save map chunks. This will dramatically reduce storage requirements. Obviously you can't load all tiles into memory at once, so you'll need a window algorithm that finds out which are visible and paints them accordingly. This is pretty elementary stuff if you spend the time to work it out on graph paper in advance.

Comment: @abdelgany Too late, you forgot to ask your question. You can delete this and ask a new (better) question. I actually have an answer for your question. But you need to reopen or rewrite another question.

Comment: @user3437460
you say " I actually have an answer for your question"
which mean I ask

Comment: You should break your world up into *tiles*.  You can reduce the memory consumption by repeating tiles or reusing them.  For example, most of the Pacific Ocean looks the same, so it can be represented by a few tiles, even though it covers a large area.

Comment: You may have to resort to drawing your world on the fly.  This is a technique that most GPS mapping software applications use.  The look up information from a database about the present location, then draw it on the fly.  They draw a larger area and have "viewport" to a smaller section.  This helps speed up operations such as rotate.

Comment: I recommend against drawing random pixels.  It will look more like a design or modern art, than a world.  In a world, like the Earth, there are regions that have similar colors and not random.  With random pixel colors, how do you define oceans and buildings?

Comment: @abdelgany `which mean I ask` Yes, you only asked it in your comments.

Comment: You can load it from the fly as others mentioned, but to me the idea of requiring 129.6 billion pixels for your game world is strange either way. Do you actually have your artists painting an image that big to the point where every single pixel is used to convey unique detail for a region of the map? It seems unlikely to me, so I would seek to instance some things -- like alpha blended layers you can stamp onto the map with some repetition, but through layered work, still allows each part of the map to look unique... or apply generate some procedural textures on the fly (no storage).

Comment: ... things of this sort. There should be a way to make your game world look really unique in every single corner and beautiful without requiring every single teeny point on the map to be represented with a unique pixel drawn and stored in advance.

Comment: Have a look at "No Man's Sky"... they use an algorithmic approach and only store deltas for when someone shoots something up.

Answer (score 1):

Leave most of the map on disk. Only load (asynchronously) the local/visible neighbourhood of tiles that you need as the player moves around.  And unload tiles that fall out of range.  Also, compress the version that's on disk.  Surely you won't have much variation with only 16 tile types.  If it's a "map" of areas of similar tile types then run length compression will likely help.

Comment: Putting a ridiculously huge thing on disk is not helping anyone. 60GB for a game map is asking a lot. Many people have a 256GB SSD and if you're booking that much space for tiles you're getting uninstalled awfully quick.

Comment: It would not be 60GB zipped.  And when you think about it, Imagine a minecraft-style world where the coordinates go up to 360000.  If I covered the whole world with stuff, that'd be worth a few gigabytes.

Comment: It depends on the data and the compression method. Minecraft worlds get really huge in a hurry and they use LZW internally.

Comment: Also, if the world is random, you can just store the state of the random number generator and regenerate the tiles as needed.  Then you only need to store a sparse array of the changes from what the random number generator made.  This is how Minecraft does it.

Comment: Minecraft procedurally generates on the fly but always persists the "chunks" once they've been instantiated. This is a known problem for multi-player servers. If someone goes running off in one direction to explore the server backups get permanently bigger.